# Cross SiteCollection call with JSOM not working

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, cross-site

I got a problem and my brain says "yes you made no mistake" but it doesn't work. Here is my problem:

I have a SharePoint hosted App which has "Tenant read" permissions in the App Manifest.

[image: App permissions are tenant read]

That App has an AppPart which is installed on Site Collection A (on the root like http://mysharepoint.com/).
I also have a SiteCollection B (like http://mysharepoint.com/sites/SiteCollectionB/) and in that Site Collection is a List. Now the App from Site Collection A wants to access Site Collection B with the Cross Site Scripting approach with JSOM.
And I always get the typical "permission denied" message

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

My Code for getting the context is written in TypeScript! Here is the part of the Code where I create the context and the web!

```
var appWebUrl: string = FuM.Helper.ParameterHelper.getWebAppUrl();
var targetWebUrl: string = "http://mysharepoint.com/sites/SiteCollectionB/";

context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appWebUrl);
context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, targetWebUrl);

getListItemsAsync("Announcements", "", "", context, appContextSite.get_web())
```

and the code to get the list items

```
static getListItemsAsync(
        listTitle: string,
        camlQuery: string,
        include: string,
        clientContext: SP.ClientContext,
        targetWeb: SP.Web): JQueryPromise<SP.ListItemCollection> {

        var deferred = $.Deferred<SP.ListItemCollection>();

        var propertyList = targetWeb.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();

        if (camlQuery !== undefined && camlQuery !== '') {
            query.set_viewXml(camlQuery);
        }

        var listItems = propertyList.getItems(query);

        if (include !== undefined && include !== '') {
            clientContext.load(listItems, include);
        } else {
            clientContext.load(listItems);
        }

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            () => { deferred.resolve(listItems); },
            (sender, args) => { FuM.Helper.LogHelper.logError(args); }
        );

        return deferred.promise();
    }
```

Does anyone see any mistake? Am I using the wrong urls to initialize or the wrong technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer** 
I haven't got any practical experience in tenant scoped apps but this is how I understood the article in MSDN

Even though the Scope is tenant but as mentioned, your app contains an APP Part. The [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179896(v=office.15).aspx) article mentions the following limitations of tenant-scoped apps:

> The following kinds of apps cannot be batch-installed:
>
> 1. Apps that contain a custom action for the ribbon. (Custom actions that are deployed as menu items are allowed
> 2. Apps that contain an app part.
> 3. In addition, note again that installation with tenant scope is not possible in the Office 365 Small Business Premium version of
>      SharePoint Online.
>
> When an App is installed in App catalog it is available for all
>   websites in that Tenancy to be installed, when we install App on each
>   Website manually it is web scoped and when it is installed as a batch
>   to all websites specified in a tenancy it is a Tenant scope App. In
>   tenancy scope it’s a single App Web shared across all Host Webs.

Hence in your case the app can access only the Host web where it is installed and nota different site collection.

Comment: Thanks for shareing that. And how can you explain that it works on SharePoint Online but not in a on premise enviroment?

I just tried it in SharePoint Online where I get no error and the same app has the problem as mentioned.

Comment: @SebastianSchütze, sorry I should have added a disclaimer that this is how I understood the article in MSDN. I haven't got any practical experience in tenant scoped apps.

Comment: I have to add a comment regarding that answer. This is actually the correct answer for SharePoint OnPremise. Only apps that are installed in the App Catalog (tenant apps) can access all site collections.

For SharePoint Online this seem to have changed (or is generally different) and an app instance installed on a site collection with tenants right can access all site collection of the tenant.